# Ошибка Jquery: отсутствует map-файл

Tags: jquery, map, javascript

Вроде, на английский не жаловался, а тут полный ступор.
Поясните, пожалуйста, свежий джиквери постоянно ругается на нехватку map-файла.
Насколько я понял, он нужен для более точного определения места ошибки в мешанине обфусцированной библиотеки.
А можно это же самое на пальцах: как работает и действительно ли он является правилом хорошего тона? Надо ли такой свой писать под свои модули?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, map — генерирует обфускатор (например [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage)). Во вторых, он нужен только для разработки и загружается исключительно в момент открытия консоли, так что обычным юзерам всё равно.

Comment: Тогда я уже совсем запутался. Если он нужен только для разработки, как сообщить JS, что я закончил разработку? ПОтому что продакшн-версия jQuery его требует, внезапно.

Comment: Я немного обманул вас, map подгружается только в момент, когда открываете консоли, а не всегда. Так что добавлять его или нет, дело ваше, просто обычно в бою ошибок не должно быть видно обычным пользователям.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить кратко, это файл, в котором содержатся ссылки на оригинальные файлы, из которых был собран один большой файл. Таким образом, можно заставить консоль отображать реальное место ошибки в читаемом, несжатом формате.

Для разработчика совет разместить на сайте этот самый map-файл на этапе отладки (jquery предоставляет уже готовые, UglifyJS, как верно заметил [@Etki](/users/16095/etki), такой генерит самостоятельно), а в продакшене удалить, чтобы не генерировать лишний трафик и, хотя бы немного, усложнить жизнь любителям порыться в исходниках.

Если map-файл отсутствует, убрать предупреждение от консоли можно в настройках, сняв галочку "Enable source maps".

Статья на Хабре - [Введение в Javascript Source Maps](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148098/) более глубокое изучение предмета.
...И ее [Оригинал](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/source-mapping)
Краткое [описание от jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)